# TFS: Why there are Pending changes from multiple projects

Tags: tfs

i have a Team Project and under this Team Project there are multiple visual studions solutions. each solution contain multiple projects.

while working on a solution , in pending changes it shows me files from other solutions as well which are checked out to me....  this is wrong.. it have to show only changes related to current solution. why it is showing me changes from all solutions.??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a button to the right of the list of buttons in the pending changes window that looks like a solution item - when this is highlighted it should only shows items for the current solution.  Sometimes you have to refresh to show the correct items.

Comment: hey i tried that button, but it still shows pending changes on my name from other projects as well :(

Comment: For some reason 'deletions' are not treated in the same way as other changes and deletions in other solutions appear even when the filter-by-solution option is set (at least in TFS 2010).

Comment: @nicodemus13 There is an explanation of why deletions are included from other solutions here (though I think it's poor IMHO!): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/885b9a08-6c79-4b3f-85f5-7668c0d33c67

Answer (score 11):

Just an update for Visual Studio 2012:  The button mentioned above appears to have been moved to a filter drop down beneath Included Changes / Excluded Changes.  Hit the dropdown and change "Show All" to "Show Solution Changes."

Comment: If "Show solution changes" is disabled, you (and your project) have been disconnected from TFS (e.g. reconnected your laptop to (another) wifi).  Go to "File" | "Source Control" | "Connect"(?) to reconnect, and this will re-enable "Show solution changes".

Answer (score 4):

Open the Team Foundation Server window in Visual studio, then click pending changes, then at included changes list you will find blue link "Show All" and small down arrow above the files list, click this arrow and select "Show Solution Changes"

Answer (score 0):

"Show Solution Changes" will greyed out when your solution is in OFFLINE mode, make sure you turn it ONLINE by following below steps.

[image]