# Where is the "Filter By Solution" button in VS2012 Team Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

In VS2010's Team Explorer there was an option to show pending changes only for the current solution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1762180/612265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4896899/612265)).  Is there equivalent functionality in VS2012, and if so how do I get to it?

Comment: Could those voting to close please explain why this question has no value to a programmer?  Questions with people asking how to do the same thing in VS2010 were deemed acceptable.  I'll be happy to rephrase/retitle if that would help.

Comment: Indeed, it's clearly not off-topic.  I'm shocked that it's not a duplicate, though!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Team Explorer pane, click "Pending Changes":

[image: Team Explorer pane]

Then on the Pending Changes pane, expand the dropdown under Included Changes and select "Show Solution Changes":

[image: Pending Changes pane]

Comment: +1, very nice.  This works for some of my solutions; for others it is grayed out.  How do I activate it?

Comment: @EvanHaas The only time I've seen that option disabled is when the solution is not under source control. I'm sure you've checked that, so I'm not sure. Sorry. It would probably help if there was a tooltip or something like that on the dropdown that explained its usage and status better.

Comment: Right click on the Solution node in Solution explorer and choose Go Online.

Comment: +1 for Tim Smojver above comment. I did what Tim Smojver said and it solved my problem. My problem was Show Solution Changes was grayed out. I opened Solution Explorer.. Right Click on Solution and clicked Go online...

Comment: I wonder why MS added such a cryptic setting. I looked for it for a few minutes and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Another method I've found for achieving the same result (filtering out pending changes that are not part of the solution I'm working on) is to create more, fine-grained TFS workspaces (as opposed to a single workspace that contains many unrelated solutions).  Once you have more than one solution, the Pending Changes view will contain a drop-down that lets you pick which workspace to show changes for:

[image: Pending Changes workspace selector]